# backface-visibility behaviour differs between Chrome and Safari

Tags: css, webkit, transform

I have a list where I want the list items to flip over to reveal new content when the user presses a button as a sort of paging. In Chrome this works as expected, but in Safari it shows the back of the original li upside down until I remove it.

I've put up a little example on http://jsfiddle.net/D2vgk/ (webkit only for now)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The overflow:hidden; property on the card was causing problems in Safari. I removed it and now the behaviour is the same as Chrome's.

I put up the latest version on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/D2vgk/10/

Comment: This worked for me in Safari and partially in iOS 4.3. However, it seems not to fix the issue in iOS 5.0+.

Comment: On an iPhone 4S with version 5.0.1 everything seems to work as expected. What behaviour are you seeing?

Comment: What I have built is slightly different, you can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/uGzyj/19/  Essentially, the "back" image shows up correctly on Chrome and desktop Safari, but iOS 5.0+ (on my 3GS and on the emulator) doesn't display the back image. Instead, it shows the backface of the "front" image.

Comment: I've updated your example. iOS for Safari seems to explicitly want you to set the the "transform-style: preserve-3d" property on the child elements as well. http://jsfiddle.net/rKY6r/

Comment: This thread was incredibly helpful, and should serve as an example of a succesful/professional use of this website, with people problem-solving, engineering, and sharing. Awesome stuff. And thanks a ton - this saved me a lot of headaches.